# sed-like attempt from database

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

The following code and test data works, but I have had to add delays between writes to MySQL otherwise it acts funny (especially on the target data set which is over 700 rows).  The table is simply a number and value (the number is another table's 'foreign key(?)'.

I am looking for suggestions on how I might reorganize this for better behavior. Perhaps a Generator? It's written in JavaScript, and uses node.js 0.10, because I believe I need to become much better in JavaScript. The real goal is to be able to change the last two funcs out to whatever data base hack I need to preform today. This code preforms a Name hack, but in the future I plan on different code that would do what ever data field hacking I need.  The mental model is `sed` for MySQL.

I ended up stripping almost all comments out as they were formatting funny.

### JavaScript for node.js 0.10

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var path = require('path');
var size = require('window-size');
var mysql = require('mysql');


/***************************************************************************************************
* Yargs setup array.  This beast describes the arguments we take, help, and defaults.              *
* See https://github.com/bcoe/yargs for detailed docs                                              *
*                                                                                                  *
***************************************************************************************************/
var argv = require('yargs')
    .usage('Usage: $0 --host=192.168.5.100 --user=dude --pass=SurfsUp! -D LexPaper ')
    .example('$0 --host=192.168.5.100 --user=jep --pass=rats --db=LexPaper')
    .demand(['host', 'user', 'pass', 'db'])
    .describe('host', 'name/IP address of computer with MySQL running')
    .describe('user', 'User name to login to MySQL with')
    .describe('pass', 'Password to login to MySQL with')
    .describe('db', 'MySQL Database that we will be using')
//    .describe('', '')
    .help('h')
    .alias('H', 'host')
    .alias('U', 'user')
    .alias('P', 'pass')
    .alias('D', 'db')
    .alias('h', 'help')
    .alias('h', '?')
    .wrap(size.width - 1)
    .version(function() { return require ('./package.json').version; })
    .argv;


var queryComplete = 0;

console.log ("------------------------------------------------------------- ");
console.log (path.basename(process.argv[1]), " running, args" + " host=" + argv.host + " user='" + argv.user + "' db='" + argv.db + "'");


var connectParms = {
   user     : argv.user,
   password : argv.pass,
   database : argv.db,
   host     : argv.host,
   port     : 3306
 };

// if host name given is the local host, add the socket pipe.
// This is only necessary if my.cnf entry 'bind-address' is not '0.0.0.0'
// This will only work as written on Linux.
/*
if (argv.host == 'localhost' || argv.host == '127.0.0.1') {
    connectParms.socketPath = '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock';
}
*/

var connection = mysql.createConnection(connectParms);

connection.connect(function(err){
    if(!err) {
        console.log("Database is connected ... \n\n");
    } else {
        console.log("Error connecting database ... " + err + "\n\n");
    }
});

console.log ("Submitting query: " + getQueryStr());
connection.query(getQueryStr(), function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (!err) {
        // console.log('Result: ', rows);
        console.log ("Number of rows in result: " + rows.length);

        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            processRow (i, rows[i]);
        }

        queryComplete = 1;

    } else {
        console.log('Error while performing Query.');
        queryComplete = 1;
    }
});


/***************************************************************************************************
* Take strings in mixed case/all upper case and make them into 'proper case' Examples:             *
* INPUT                    Output                                                                  *
* ACE CHEMICALS            Ace Chemicals                                                           *
* SIONIS STEEL MILL        Sionis Steel Mill                                                       *
*                                                                                                  *
* Code by http://stackoverflow.com/users/360053/tuan                                               *
* Found on StackOverflow:                                                                          *
* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196972/convert-string-to-title-case-with-javascript/196991#196991
*                                                                                                  *
***************************************************************************************************/
String.prototype.toProperCase = function () {
    return this.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});
};

/***************************************************************************************************
* Left pad string with pad character.  Examples:                                                   *
* xx="4";    xx.lpad("0", 5) = '00004'                                                             *
* xx="55";   xx.lpad("0", 3) = '055'                                                               *
* xx="155";  xx.lpad("0", 3) = '155'                                                               *
* xx="0";  xx.lpad("0", 3) = '000'                                                                 *
* xx="8";  xx.lpad(" ", 3) = '  8'                                                                 *
*                                                                                                  *
* Code by: http://stackoverflow.com/users/155861/diecho                                            *
* Found on StackOverflow:                                                                          *
* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073699/pad-a-number-with-leading-zeros-in-javascript        *
*                                                                                                  *
***************************************************************************************************/
String.prototype.lpad = function(padString, length) {
    var str = this;
    while (str.length < length)
        str = padString + str;
    return str;
};

/***************************************************************************************************
* Replace one or more characters in a string.                                                      *
* We need this because JavaScript strings are immutable, thus what we want, to change a single     *
* character in a string is 'impossible'.  This returns a new string with the changes the caller    *
* wants, allowing them the illusion of a mutable string.                                           *
*                                                                                                  *
* Code by: http://stackoverflow.com/users/173347/cem-kalyoncu                                      *
* Found on StackOverflow:                                                                          *
* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431094/how-do-i-replace-a-character-at-a-particular-index-in-javascript
*                                                                                                  *
***************************************************************************************************/
String.prototype.replaceAt = function(index, character) {
    return this.substr(0, index) + character + this.substr(index + character.length);
};


/***************************************************************************************************
* Exit pause.  Since we are just a command line program, we may exit too quickly for MySQL to      *
* reply before we terminate.  This func will either clean up after N half second pauses, or sooner *
* if the global query complete flag has been set.                                                  *
*                                                                                                  *
*                                                                                                  *
***************************************************************************************************/
(function wait () {
    if (typeof wait.counter == 'undefined' ) {
        // No such variable in the wait prototype, invent it
        wait.counter = 0;
    }

    wait.counter += 1;
    console.log ("count= " + wait.counter + "  queryComplete= " + queryComplete);

    if ((wait.counter < 5) && (queryComplete < 2)) {
        if (queryComplete > 0)
            queryComplete += 1;

        setTimeout(wait, 500);

    } else {
        connection.end();
    }
})();


function getQueryStr () {
    var qry = '';
    qry = 'SELECT * from Customers';
    return qry;
}

var convertTable = [
    { search: "Lex Corp.", replacment: "Lex Corp.", searchEnd: false, fixCase: false },

    { search: "COMP.", replacment: "Company",       searchEnd: true, fixCase: true },
    { search: "FACT.", replacment: "Factory",       searchEnd: true, fixCase: true },
    { search: "CORP.", replacment: "Corporation",   searchEnd: true, fixCase: true },
    { search: "INDUS.", replacment: "industries",   searchEnd: true, fixCase: true },
    { search: "PROD.", replacment: "products",      searchEnd: true, fixCase: true },
    { search: "MFG.", replacment: "Manufacturing",  searchEnd: true, fixCase: true },
    { search: "DIST.", replacment: "Distribution",  searchEnd: true, fixCase: true },
    { search: " INC", replacment: " Inc.",         searchEnd: true, fixCase: true }
];

function processRow (row, dat) {
    var oldStr = dat.CustomerName;
    var len = oldStr.length;
    var newStr = "";
    var fixed = false;
    var padStr = "                                                                                                               ";
    var tmpStr = "";
    var orgin = 0;

    //  tmpStr = row.toString().lpad("0", 3);
    //  console.log('ROW' + tmpStr, dat);

    for (var i = 0; i < convertTable.length; i++) {
        if (convertTable[i].searchEnd)
            orgin = oldStr.length - convertTable[i].search.length;
        else
            orgin = 0;

        if (oldStr.indexOf (convertTable[i].search, orgin) != -1) {
            newStr = oldStr.replace (convertTable[i].search, convertTable[i].replacment);

            // console.log ("YYY Search=[" + convertTable[i].search + "] fixCase=" + convertTable[i].fixCase);
            if (convertTable[i].fixCase) {
                newStr = newStr.toProperCase();

                if ((newStr.charAt(1) == "&") || (newStr.charAt(1) == "-") || (newStr.charAt(1) == ".")) {
                    //console.log ("ZZZ");
                    newStr = newStr.replaceAt (2, newStr.charAt(2).toUpperCase());
                }
            }

            fixed = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!fixed) {
        newStr = oldStr.toProperCase();

        if ((newStr.charAt(1) == "&") || (newStr.charAt(1) == "-") || (newStr.charAt(1) == ".")) {
            newStr = newStr.replaceAt (2, newStr.charAt(2).toUpperCase());
        }

        // Strip trailing period
        // newStr = oldStr.slice(0, - 1);
    }

    //  tmpStr = row.toString().lpad("0", 3);
    //  console.log('ROW' + tmpStr + ':  original=[' + oldStr + "]" + padStr.slice(0, 30 - len) + (fixed ? "CUST" : " std") + "=[" + newStr + "]");


    // ---------------------------- All rules applied.  Now put back into data base
    dat.CustomerName = newStr;
    dat.JetDB_CustomerName = oldStr;


    var sql = "UPDATE Customers SET CustomerName=?,JetDB_CustomerName=? WHERE CustomerSequence=?";
    var inserts = [dat.CustomerName,dat.JetDB_CustomerName,dat.CustomerSequence];
    sql = mysql.format(sql, inserts);

    tmpStr = row.toString().lpad('0', 3);
    console.log ('ROW' + tmpStr + ': SQL=', sql);

    connection.query (sql, function(err, result) {
        if (err)
            console.log ("Row# " + row + " ERROR: ", err);
        else
            console.log ("Row# " + row + " successfully changed");
    });

    return;
}
```

### Test environment (not for review)

SQL file that will create a test database:

```
--
-- Company fix test data set
--

CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `LexPaper` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_cs;
USE LexPaper;

-- DELETE from Customers where CustomerSequence like '%';

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Customers`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Customers` (
    `CustomerSequence` int(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `CustomerName` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_cs NOT NULL DEFAULT 'nobody',
    `JetDB_CustomerName` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_cs NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`CustomerSequence`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=690 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT into Customers (CustomerName) VALUES ('ACE CHEMICALS'),('ARKHAM PROD.'),('J&P INDU.'),('BLACKGATE TOOL&DIE'),('SIONIS STEEL MILL'),('TWO FACE DIST.');
INSERT into Customers (CustomerName) VALUES ('PENGUINN PROD.'),('PLANT FACT.'),('MILLER MUSIC DIST.'),('SPRANG MFG.'),('ROBINSON PIZZA DIST.'),('R.H. KANE MFG.');
INSERT into Customers (CustomerName) VALUES ('DIXON DOCK DIST.'),('GRANT PARK INDUS.'),('WAYNE FACT.'),('VICTOR FRIES CORP.'),('JOKER COMP.'),('TWO FACE SLOT MACHINE MFG.');
INSERT into Customers (CustomerName) VALUES ('DOCKSIDE PAPER PROD.'),('BASIL KARLO GRAVEL DIST.'),('Lex Corp.'),('Bane Hammers'),('Pennyworth PROD.'),('ZATANNA MAGIC DIST.');
INSERT into Customers (CustomerName) VALUES ('lucius fox mfg.'),('grason climbing prod.'),('NAPIER&COBBLEPOT TOYS'),('Ra\'s al Ghul Knives'),('Daggett Tool&Die'),('FUGATE TIMEPIECES');
INSERT into Customers (CustomerName) VALUES ('Talia al Ghul Publicity'),('BUZZ BRONSKI MFG.'),('HARLEEN QUINZELL COMP.'),('EDWARD NYGMA GAMES');
INSERT into Customers (CustomerName) VALUES ('D&T LINGERIE'),('D&T JETS'),('D&T WHIPS'),('D&T Chains'),('Diana CHIPS'),('Selina Kyle');

-- Getting tired of inventing company names
INSERT into Customers (CustomerName) VALUES ('frank boles'),('SONDRA FULLER'),('NORA FRIES'),('EVA GREEN'),('GREY LORA'),('SOLOMON GRUNDY'),('JILL HAMPTON'),('CHARLOTTE RIVERS');
INSERT into Customers (CustomerName) VALUES ('karin grace'),('HARLEY QUINN'),('IBN HASSAN'),('HOLLY WOOD'),('DOCTOR AESOP'),('DEACON BLACKFIRE'),('DOCTOR PHOSPHORUS'),('BLACK ALICE');
INSERT into Customers (CustomerName) VALUES ('JOE CHILL'),('KILLER CROC'),('KING KRAKEN'),('CARL KRUGER'),('MAGGIE KYLE'),('LADY SHIVA'),('ARNOLD FLASS'),('TERRENCE CLARK');
INSERT into Customers (CustomerName) VALUES ('DAVID CAIN'),('FERRIS BOYLE'),('ROSE WILSON'),('ROXY ROCKET'),('AMANDA WALLER'),('XAVIER SIMON'),('SIMON STAGG'),('VICTOR ZSASZ');
-- INSERT into Customers (CustomerName) VALUES (''),(''),(''),(''),(''),(''),(''),('');


-- Remove BINARY for case insensitive sorting
SELECT * from Customers ORDER by BINARY CustomerName DESC limit 20;

-- DELETE from Customers where CustomerSequence > 689;
```

### Sample command lines showing use:

```
# Create data base and populate it.  No my user name is not 'dude'.
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -t -udude -pCowaBunga  <dataSet.sql

# This will re-build the data base.  Not sure if it will work very first time
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -t -udude -pCowaBunga -D LexPaper <dataSet.sql

# Node.js program.  Magic sequence at start of file allows direct run from command line
./nameFix.js --host=127.0.0.1 --user=dude --pass=CowaBunga --db=LexPaper

# View the table
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -t -udude -pCowaBunga -D LexPaper -e "SELECT * from Customers;"
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "DB-Hack",
  "description": "Open the MySQL database and strip the trailing periods from all customer names",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "mysql": "*",
    "window-size": "^0.1.1",
    "yargs": "*"
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `ascii`? Why not `latin1` or `utf8`?

Comment: The original data base this was based off of used ASCII, by habit I kept it the same.  To make this more useful to others in the future I am going to change the encoding to latin1.  Other layers required case case insensitive sorting, and at best as I can tell MySQL 5.5 does not support UTF-8 case insensitive behavior.

Comment: Actually, MySQL does support it. You have `utf8_unicode_ci` and `utf8_general_ci`. I actually recommend using `utf8` in this case, since it can, in some ways, be seen as a multi-byte superset of `ascii` (every valid `ascii` character, without counting the control characters, is a valid `utf8` character.). You can read about the differences on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766809/whats-the-difference-between-utf8-general-ci-and-utf8-unicode-ci

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> if (typeof wait.counter == 'undefined' ) {
> ```

Checking if something is undefined by checking it's type is unnecessary. Since `undefined` is a falsey value, simply putting the thing you'd like to check in a conditional will do the trick:

```
if( !wait.counter ) {
```

---

> ```
> console.log ("count= " + ++(wait.counter) + "  queryComplete= " + queryComplete);
> ```

All those `+` signs between `"count= "` and `"  queryComplete= "` are a little confusing. It seems like you tried to make it more readable by putting `()`s around `wait.counter`, but it would be more readable if you just moved `++wait.counter` to a line of it's own.

```
++wait.counter;
console.log ("count= " + wait.counter + "  queryComplete= " + queryComplete);
```

*Thanks to IsmaelMiguel for recommending to move the `++wait.counter` out of `console.log` all together.*

---

Add some documentation to your functions to describe what they are doing, what they need, why they need it, and what it is returning.

---

This is all I can review, as I am not familiar with SQL.

---

P.S.

```
fixed = true;
break;
```

Comment: I don't check here every day, but I wrote

    if (typeof wait.counter == 'undefined')

very consciously.  The first time wait() runs there is no such element in the function's object.  So I 'invent' the counter.  All subsequent loops increment the now present counter.  I also remember that in JavaScript a value of 0 is falsey, I need to know the difference between zero and non-existent.

Comment: @JamesPowell I am sorry, I don't quite understand what this message means. Is it a question? If you'd like, you could join me in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22584/sirpythons-mansion) and type `@SirPython` to get my attention, where you could then ask your question(s).

Comment: Hi, thanks for paying attention.  No, my words were not a question.  Somewhere above you had indicated that my use of == 'undefined' was un-necesasary, and I was defending my syntax choice.